# When will the first LTS version be released featuring Gnome shell as default?

Tags: gnome, versions

Some time ago, we received the big news, that Unity gets ditched and replaced by Gnome. I'm a Ubuntu Gnome user and so I really appreciate this decision.

When will the very first LTS version be released featuring the Gnome shell as the graphical environment?

Comment: I recall reading that Gnome would be default for 18.04, but I don't have a reference handy.

Comment: Looks like 18.04, April 2018.

Comment: Technically speaking, 10.04 was the first LTS release with a default GNOME GUI. 8.04 was also LTS, but only for the server release. 18.04 will theoretically be the first with gnome-shell as default.

Comment: @dobey Oh c'mon.

Comment: What? 10.04 was GNOME 2.x: https://www.geek.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/Ubuntu_10_04-Beta2.jpg

Comment: @dobey I didn't "oh c'mon" the stated facts (they are true of course) but rather your acting that you got me wrong. You know exactly what I meant.

Comment: @dobey I've updated the question to address your concerns.

Comment: Also, the question is about future releases of Ubuntu, so is off topic. While 18.04 is currently planned to have GNOME as the default, it is not yet released, and development plans may change. A lot can change in 6 months.

Comment: @dobey - true the question is off topic but I can not imagine a large enough change such that gnome/wayland will not be the default ubuntu desktop in 17.10 and beyond.

Comment: @dobey Is this off-topic as a "UI and theme question"? It doesn't seem to be a "bug report" or "problem specific to" a development version of Ubuntu, so the close reason people have been selecting here at least *seems* wrong. This doesn't seem like it falls under ["*issues with* the next version of Ubuntu"](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) (emphasis mine). And that help page [links here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/871), where the [top-voted answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/872) (reflecting the community's expressed consensus) doesn't *seem* to support closing this sort of question.

Comment: @EliahKagan Seems like it would fall under the "UI and theme" questions clause of "Shouldn't be allowed" in that linked answer.  It's asking about a release of Ubuntu that development hasn't even started on yet as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be Ubuntu 18.04, the upcoming LTS release [as announced in the Ubuntu GNOME blog back in April.](https://ubuntugnome.org/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-released/) Given that you are already using Ubuntu GNOME, you will (most likely) not be affected by this change, and your desktop will escape relatively untouched if that's what you're worried about.

> On 5 April 2017 Mark Shuttleworth announced that Canonical's work on
>   Unity will end and that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, a year away from release at
>   the time, will abandon the Unity desktop and employ the GNOME 3
>   desktop instead, as Canonical moves away from its ambitions to produce
>   a unified cell phone and desktop operating system and concentrates on
>   desktop, cloud computing and Internet of things platforms instead.
>   UBports founder Marius Gripsgård announced that the organization would
>   continue Unity development.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(Ubuntu)